# PHP Mailer Subject getting wrong

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

I tried to send mail using php mailer the mail was send perfectly but subject getting like this

```
=??Q?=54=65=6C=6C=2D=55=53=20=59=6F=75=72=20=53=74=6F=72=79?=
```

This is my mail content controller.

```
$this->load->library('email');
    $name="*****";
    $email="*******@gmail.com";

    $subject = 'Tell-US Your Story';
    $message = '<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
    <li><p><b>Name:</b>$nbsp;'.$name.'</p></li>
    <li><p><b>Email:</b>'.$email.'</p></li>
    </ul>';
    // <title>' .$subject. '</title>

// Get full html:
    $body = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=' . strtolower(config_item('charset')) . '" />
    <title>test mail</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
    <h2>'.$subject.'</h2>
    ' . $message . '</<div>
    </body>
    </html>';
    // Also, for getting full html you may use the following internal method:
    //$body = $this->email->full_html($subject, $message);
    $result = 
    $this->email
    ->from('*******@example.in')
    ->reply_to('')    // Optional, an account where a human being reads.
    ->to('********@gmail.com')
    ->subject("Tell-US")
    ->message($body)
    ->send();
    var_dump($result);
    echo '<br />';
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Somebody please help me to solve this problem.

Thanking you

Comment: Are you using latest PHPMailer? Can you set `CharSet=‘UTF-8’`?

Comment: I have done like this but still now also its getting like that.